# PHP MySQL - How do I create a database? Current Error: No Database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database

I followed a tutorial for a class but I keep getting the error message:

```
Error creating table: No database selected
```

I am a beginner and I am not really sure "why" I am getting this error and how to solve it - thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername);
mysqli_select_db($conn,"myDB");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS muq
        (   muqUD INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            dateTime DATETIME,
            taskTime FLOAT(4,2),
            useTime VARCHAR(60),
            usedM VARCHAR(40),
            freqRate VARCHAR(200),
            gender CHAR(1),
            age TINYINT UNSIGNED,
            email VARCHAR(100),
            comment VARCHAR(3000))          
        ";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table muq created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you didn't include a username (and password) for it, if a password is required. If it isn't required, it still should be an argument as empty.

Comment: if your query was solved please accept the answer that was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create connection in one line like the following

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```